# In my Django template, how do I display the check boxes and notification types?

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

If this is the view in Django_notification (https://github.com/pinax/django-notification/blob/master/notification/views.py), how do I display the check box? It doesn't seem like there are form objects here.  Usually, I'm used to doing this: {{ myform.thefield }}

```
@login_required
def notice_settings(request):
    """
    The notice settings view.

    Template: :template:`notification/notice_settings.html`

    Context:

        notice_types
            A list of all :model:`notification.NoticeType` objects.

        notice_settings
            A dictionary containing ``column_headers`` for each ``NOTICE_MEDIA``
            and ``rows`` containing a list of dictionaries: ``notice_type``, a
            :model:`notification.NoticeType` object and ``cells``, a list of
            tuples whose first value is suitable for use in forms and the second
            value is ``True`` or ``False`` depending on a ``request.POST``
            variable called ``form_label``, whose valid value is ``on``.
    """
    notice_types = NoticeType.objects.all()
    settings_table = []
    for notice_type in notice_types:
        settings_row = []
        for medium_id, medium_display in NOTICE_MEDIA:
            form_label = "%s_%s" % (notice_type.label, medium_id)
            setting = get_notification_setting(request.user, notice_type, medium_id)
            if request.method == "POST":
                if request.POST.get(form_label) == "on":
                    if not setting.send:
                        setting.send = True
                        setting.save()
                else:
                    if setting.send:
                        setting.send = False
                        setting.save()
            settings_row.append((form_label, setting.send))
        settings_table.append({"notice_type": notice_type, "cells": settings_row})

    if request.method == "POST":
        next_page = request.POST.get("next_page", ".")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_page)

    notice_settings = {
        "column_headers": [medium_display for medium_id, medium_display in NOTICE_MEDIA],
        "rows": settings_table,
    }

    return render_to_response("notification/notice_settings.html", {
        "notice_types": notice_types,
        "notice_settings": notice_settings,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default template for this view is checked into github: https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/templates/default/notification/notice_settings.html

UPDATE: Pinax removed their themes, the last checkin with templates can still be found [here](https://github.com/pinax/pinax/tree/7f5c31fbcf455767dc7bc79a53be39038e00786f/pinax/themes/default/templates/notification).

There is no form defined for the notification settings object, so the checkbox elements (and the form itself) are created using raw HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action=""> {# doubt this easy to do in uni-form #}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table class="notice_settings">
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans "Notification Type" %}</th>
                {% for header in notice_settings.column_headers %}
                    <th>{{ header }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% for row in notice_settings.rows %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{% trans row.notice_type.display %}<br/>
                        <span class="notice_type_description">{% trans row.notice_type.description %}</span>
                    </td>
                    {% for cell in row.cells %}
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ cell.0 }}" {% if cell.1 %}checked="yes"{% endif %}/>
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="{% trans "Change" %}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Yup that's more like it, you need to add a <input type="checkbox" name="form_label" checked="on"/> in that form

Answer (score 0):

The view you show only manages the processing of the POSTed notification but not the displaying of a form in a page. You can create your own form that includes a field called `form_label` and include it in whatever page that posts to this view (could be a hidden input).

Comment: the send methods is for sending notifications. This is for settings.